# Is the phrase "Frustrated of feeling mute, .." correct?

Tags: word-choice

I know that frustrated is usually paired with 'by'; however, in this case is does not sound right. Is the given phrase correct? If not, what would be an appropriate way to phrase it.

My sentence is structured like this:

"Frustrated of feeling mute, I decided to..."

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You need to give more context of how this phrase is used.

Comment: I apologize, I thought it was clear. I edited the question and included more context.

Comment: Don't use *of*, use *with*: "Frustrated with feeling mute . . ."

Answer (score 1):

It's acceptable, but I'd prefer "by" to "of."

Comment: "By" makes the sentence mean that are feeling mute in order to be frustrated.  Similar to: *I am keeping busy by scrubbing the floor.*  I'd prefer *with*

Comment: Sorry, your response isn't coherent.  "By" in context suggests that the frustration is being caused directly by the muting, whereas "with" suggests that the frustration is associated with the long term effect.  Frustration is a short term thing, so whereas this depends on the expected conveyed feeling, "by" is almost certainly what they mean, I feel.

It's usually best to leave your own answer, on matters of preference and opinion.

Comment: In my case, I am using it to indicate a long term effect, hence I chose to use 'with'.

Comment: @JohnHaugeland- Sorry, I dropped a word while typing.  It should read, *"By" makes the sentence mean that **they** are feeling mute in order to be frustrated*.

Comment: I disagree with your assessment